# google app engine, webapp2, DomainRoute and lazy handlers

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to support a more or less isolated app inside my main GAE application, hosted at different subdomain.

I put the handlers for this subdomain in the file "mediciones.py", inside the "oficina" folder.

So I have:

1. /main.py
2. /oficina/mediciones.py
3. And inside mediciones.py:

```python
class Router(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      [... code ...]

class Listado(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      [... code ...]
```

Etc. for all the necessary handlers.

Inside "main.py":

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    DomainRoute('ventas.domain.com',
        [webapp2.Route(r'/nueva', handler='oficina.mediciones.MedicionNueva', name="nueva-medicion"),
         webapp2.Route(r'/listado', handler="oficina.mediciones.Listado", name="listado-mediciones"),
         webapp2.Route(r'/medicion/(\d+)/', handler="oficina.mediciones.MedicionDetalles", name="detalles-mediciones"),
         webapp2.Route(r'/rellenar_medicion/(\d+)/', handler="oficina.mediciones.MedicionRellenar", name="rellenar-medicion"),
         webapp2.Route(r'/editar_medicion/(\d+)/', handler="oficina.mediciones.MedicionEditar", name="editar-medicion"),
         webapp2.Route('/', handler="oficina.mediciones.Router")
        ]),
('/(.+)',
     DirectView),
    ('/?',
        HomeView),
    ], debug=True)
```

But when I try to go to ventas.domain.com, or to ventas.domain.com/listado, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1272, in default_dispatcher
    self.handlers[handler] = handler = import_string(handler)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1851, in import_string
    return getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj)
ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'oficina.mediciones.Router'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Original exception:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Router'

Debugged import:

- 'oficina' found in '/base/data/home/apps/s~pavimentos-arquiservi-web-hrd/11-0-0.361841284178483516/oficina/__init__.pyc'.
- 'oficina.mediciones' found in '/base/data/home/apps/s~pavimentos-arquiservi-web-hrd/11-0-0.361841284178483516/oficina/mediciones/__init__.pyc'.
- 'oficina.mediciones.Router' not found.
```

(Replace "Router" by "Listado", or the appropriate handler for each situation).

Handlers are defined, but why isn't it finding them in their place?

Comment: Can you `import oficina.mediciones.Router` in `main.py`?

Comment: did you include: from webapp2_extras import routes

Comment: Problem was that there were an additional package mediciones inside the "oficina" folder. So I had a file "mediciones.py" and a folder/package "mediciones", and that got Python (and myself) confused.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is really self contained, you might consider a different method to split the handlers in a separate module. In your `app.yaml` you can define a different url prefix and have it handled by a different module.

E.g.

```
- url: /oficina/.*
  script: ofinina.mediciones.py

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

Unfortunately, you cannot separate these routes simply by domain name, so, depending on your requirements, this may not be an option for you.

As an alternative, instead of using string names for your handlers, you can import the required package into your main.py and use the class names directly. This reduces the self-containment of your packages. But then again, so does referring to class names by string literals.

Comment: Problem with that is that I really want to separate apps by domain name.

I'm integrating apps that were deployed separately into a single app because I can use some data-sharing between them, and I don't want users to have to use a different url (as in domain.com/ventas instead of ventas.domain.com).

Besides, I would also like to understand why isn't this working... :P

Thanks!

Comment: You can still do that. Only you must __also__ add a url prefix.